# Optimizing generalized ternary search

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

There are $N$ socks numbered $1$ to $N$, one containing a gift. Dave needs to find the sock with the gift. He can ask some questions in order to find that sock: in each question, Dave chooses $2$ numbers $P,Q$ where $P \le Q$.

Let $X$ be the index of sock containing the gift .

- If $X \le P$ , Dave pays $A$ dollars.
- If $ P \lt X \le Q$, Dave pays $B$ dollars.
- If $ Q \lt X $, Dave pays $C$ dollars.

Given the values of $A,B,C$, how to find the minimum number of dollars that Dave has to pay in order to find the gift?

Comment: An interesting question. Seems we should divide into parts with equal "expected prices". Intuitively, the length of search is log of the length of interval, so the parts $x,y,z$ in which $P,Q$ divide the interval should be such that $A\log x \approx B\log y\approx C\log z$. But these are just heuristics.

Comment: Please Elaborate.I couldn't get it.

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem for the case where Dave asks a single number $P$ at each step and pays $A$ if $X\le P$, and $B$ if $X>P$ (binary search)?